# page going up when switch between links in my jsp page. How can I avoid this?

Tags: jquery, jsp

```
I have following code in my jsp page
<div  class="listtable roundBox" >
            <br>
            <ul id="breadcrumbs">         
                <li>
                    <a href='#' id='oneday' data-pid="1">1 day</a>
                </li>

                <li>               
                    <a href='#' id='fivedays' data-pid="5">5 days</a>                    
                </li>            
            </ul>             
            <div id="firstChart"  style="height:400px;width:98%; "></div>
        </div>
```

When switch between 1 day and 5 days the page is going up. How can I set focus on this div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jquery library loaded then you can do this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#breadcrumbs a').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) is used to stop the default behavior of an `anchor`, `form elements` etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `#` in the `href` attribute of the `a` element. It's used to denote a bookmark link. If there are no bookmarks set in the page, the browser defaults to the start of the document. You can use jQuery to prevent this behaviour:

```
$('#breadcrumbs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you need to follow the link only when one is specified, use this:

```
$('#breadcrumbs a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).prop('href') == '#' && e.preventDefault();
});
```